# What is real difference (if any) between Class and Class<?>?

Tags: java, generics

I'm curious is there any real difference between usage of raw `Class` type and generic `Class<?>` one? I actively use both Java SE 6 and SE 7.
At least Oracle generics tutorial has no answer to this question and my initial try to google around did not bring any suitable result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class is actually not raw type, it is called `unknown type` or [`unbounded wildcard`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html)

From Java doc:

**Unbounded Wildcards**

> `The unbounded wildcard type is specified using the wildcard character`
>   `(?), for example, List<?>. This is called a list of unknown type.`
>   `There are two scenarios where an unbounded wildcard is a useful`
>   `approach:`
>
> `If you are writing a method that can be implemented using`
>   `functionality provided in the Object class. When the code is using`
>   `methods in the generic class that don't depend on the type parameter.`
>   `For example, List.size or List.clear. In fact, Class<?> is so often`
>   `used because most of the methods in Class<T> do not depend on T.`

Answer (score 1):

The unbounded wildcard <?> appears to mean "anything", and so using an unbounded wildcard seems equivalent to using a raw type. Indeed, the compiler seems at first to agree with this assessment:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UnboundedWildcards1 {
    static List list1;
    static List<?> list2;
    static List<? extends Object> list3;

    static void assign1(List list) {
        list1 = list;
        list2 = list;
        // list3 = list; // Warning: unchecked conversion
        // Found: List, Required: List<? extends Object>
    }

    static void assign2(List<?> list) {
        list1 = list;
        list2 = list;
        list3 = list;
    }

    static void assign3(List<? extends Object> list) {
        list1 = list;
        list2 = list;
        list3 = list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assign1(new ArrayList());
        assign2(new ArrayList());
        // assign3(new ArrayList()); // Warning:
        // Unchecked conversion. Found: ArrayList
        // Required: List<? extends Object>
        assign1(new ArrayList<String>());
        assign2(new ArrayList<String>());
        assign3(new ArrayList<String>());
        // Both forms are acceptable as List<?>:
        List<?> wildList = new ArrayList();
        wildList = new ArrayList<String>();
        assign1(wildList);
        assign2(wildList);
        assign3(wildList);
    }
}
```

There are many cases like the ones you see here where the compiler could care less whether you use a raw type or <?>. In those cases, <?> can be thought of as a decoration; and yet it is valuable because, in effect, it says, **"I wrote this code with Java generics in mind, and I don't mean here that I'm using a raw type, but that in this case the generic parameter can hold any type."**

A second example shows an important use of unbound wildcards. When you are dealing with multiple generic parameters, it's sometimes important to allow one parameter to be any type while establishing a particular type for the other parameter:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UnboundedWildcards2 {
    static Map map1;
    static Map<?, ?> map2;
    static Map<String, ?> map3;

    static void assign1(Map map) {
        map1 = map;
    }

    static void assign2(Map<?, ?> map) {
        map2 = map;
    }

    static void assign3(Map<String, ?> map) {
        map3 = map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assign1(new HashMap());
        assign2(new HashMap());
        // assign3(new HashMap()); // Warning:
        // Unchecked conversion. Found: HashMap
        // Required: Map<String,?>
        assign1(new HashMap<String, Integer>());
        assign2(new HashMap<String, Integer>());
        assign3(new HashMap<String, Integer>());
    }
}
```

But again, when you have all unbounded wildcards, as seen in **Map<?,?>**, the compiler doesn't seem to distinguish it from a raw **Map**. In addition, the first example shows that the compiler treats **List<?>** and **List<? extends Object>** differently.

For more information you are welcome to read Bruce Eckel's book: [Thinking in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486)